# Echarts Resize problem in Vue3, resize function throw an error

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, resize, echarts

I was trying to draw a very simple linechart from echarts. And everything went just well **untill I tried to resize my chart**

My code goes like this(this is Vue3 composition API)

```js
const listenResize = debounce(() => {
  myChart.value?.resize()
}, 800)

window.addEventListener('resize',listenResize)
const handleChange = (type: SelectType) => {
  const option = getData(props.lineData[type])
  if (!myChart.value) {
    myChart.value = echarts.init(chartRef.value)
  }
  option && myChart.value.setOption(option);
}
const getData = (value: Array<ChartData>) => {
  ...
  return option;
};

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize',listenResize)
})
```

when I manually resize my browser and this would appear.
[image]
and I tried to find the source code of echarts, apparently this **coordinateSystem** became undefined when resizing
[image]

why did this happen? Is there anything wrong in my code?

How am I gonna solve this?

Comment: BTY, this is my echarts version. "echarts": "^5.4.3",

Comment: This is not enough code to answer. A [stackbltz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) would be helpful. What is inside the `myChart` variable? What option are you using? Its always helpful to build a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) even for your own debugging.

Comment: **mychart** is a simple ref, it was a null before initialize, it's just an echart instance nothing special. and option goes like
```typescript
  const option = {
    tooltip: {},
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      data: [
    "2023-09",
    "2023-10",
    "2023-11",
    "2023-12",
    "2024-01"
],
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: "value",
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [
    2590,
    7410,
    10653,
    19079,
    4700
],
        type: "line",
      },
    ],
  };
```
I dont think this would effect resize

Comment: if `myChart` is an echarts instance, does it have a property `value`?

Comment: dude, this is Vue's syntactic

Comment: I dont know vue. 
I know of some issues echarts has with typescript. You could try running plain javascript if thats possible and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like I fixed this problem on my own.

So I changes `myChart` to a normal JS variation instead of a ref variation in Vue3.

Because in Vue 3, `ref` is used to create a reactive reference, so that when the value of the reference changes, any place that uses this ref will be re-rendered. However I don't really need to re-render the canvas in this case.

my previous references.

```
const chartRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
const myChart = ref<ECharts | null> = (null)
```

changed to

```
const chartRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
let myChart: ECharts | null = null
```

However this only seems to be a problem in **linechart** in **biechart**.